# How to find square root of a number using a recursive function?

Tags: c

Basically i want to create a recursive function to implement this program in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float guess=1,num,num1;
    int i;
    printf("enter any number:\n");
    scanf("%f",&num);
    num1=num;
    for (i=1;num1>1;i++,num1/=10); //to calculate no of digits in input
    i=i/2;
    printf("i:%d\n",i);             //to make a better guess
    for (;i>0;i--,guess*=10);
    printf("guess = %f\n",guess);

    for (i=1;i<=10;i++)      //evaluate square root improving accuracy with each loop
    {
        guess=(guess+num/guess)/2;
    }
    printf("sqrt: %f\n",guess);  
}
```

Comment: Aaaand...what happens when you run it?

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive?

Comment: And you need help with... what?

Comment: Homework much? Show us how you have tried to implement the recursive function and we'll help you fix any mistakes.

Comment: Any loop can be turned into a recursive function. Random people on the Internet will not always be willing to do this for you. Figure out how to do it for yourself.

Comment: well if this is a homework you should consider tagging it. also what is the `question` here

Comment: I was facing problem in the **base case**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

float MySqrt(float num, float prev)
{
    float next = (prev+num/prev)/2;
    if (fabs(next-prev)<FLT_EPSILON*next)
        return next;
    return MySqrt(num, next);
}
```

To call it, pass `1.0` as your initial guess for the `prev` parameter.

You can easily make this fail with a stack overflow by passing in bad data, but you probably aren't going to be tested on that in this assignment.

Comment: fixed point fixed point *srry for the pun.. :)*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Suggested improvement: use `FLT_EPSILON` from `<float.h>` in place of hardcoded `1e-6`.

Comment: @yi_H OK, now I get it. I do actually have a PhD in Pure Maths but that was so long ago, and I'm so immersed in computed than the only thing I could make fixed point into was the counter part to floating point! Shame on me!

Comment: @Alexandre Good point. I suspect that you could even get away with testing `next==prev`.

Comment: @David: there are probably roundoff issues involved. But I suspect too that this should be equivalent.

Comment: lol. c'mon man. I probably wouldn't get it either if I haven't watched the SICP lectures. it's a real treasury.

Comment: Couldn't get the logic behind **FLT_EPSILON*next**

Comment: @rawsun the idea is that you refine the solution until each iteration is no longer changing the answer. This is a homework assignment right?

Comment: This will crash your computer if you try to calculate the square root of 0.0: next will always be prev / 2. When prev gets small, FLT_EPSILON * next will be zero, and fabs (prev - next) is obviously not less than zero, so another recursive call is made.

Comment: @gnasher729 As stated in the final paragraph