# Square Root (Newton's Algorithm) Using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, square-root

Can someone explain to me this recursive pseudocode that finds the square root of a number? I find it difficult to understand since I'm not given what n, p, and e inputs stand for. Thanks.

```
if abs(e^2 - n) < p
    SR(n,p,e) = e     
else
    SR(n,p,e) = SR(n,p,(e+n/e)/2)

(e begins at n)
```

Comment: p seems to be a tolerance for the precission of the algorithm

Comment: This spells it out a little better:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002094/how-to-find-square-root-of-a-number-using-a-recursive-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n is the number you want the square root of, e is an estimate for the square root, and p is the precision you want, i.e. the error you are willing to tolerate. The algorithm says: if e is "close enough" to the answer, i.e. e^2 is within p of n, then e is the answer you are looking for; otherwise, try a better estimate, (e+n/e)2. Why is that a better estimate? if e is larger than sqrt(n), then n/e will be smaller than sqrt(n), so sqrt(n) will be between e and n/e, so try the average of e and n/e as your next estimate. (And vice versa if e is less than sqrt(n)).

Hope this helps,

Bruce

Answer (score 1):

There's rather more to Newton's algorithm than just going from one estimate to a "better estimate".  There's some detailed maths behind why the better estimate is what it is.

The idea is that to find the solution to ANY equation of the form `f(x) = 0`, (apart from a few exceptional cases), if you have an approximation to `x`, you can get a BETTER approximation, by looking at the rate of change of `f(x)`, which is often written `f'(x)`, and using that to work out how much you have to adjust your estimate by, to get a much better estimate of the true solution.

In the case of a square root, that is, we want to find `x=sqrt(n)`, we can write `f(x)=x^2-n` and `f'(x)=2x`, then use Newton's algorithm to find the right `x` to make `f(x)=0`.  What this means is that if we have an estimate `e`, then to work out our next estimate, we look at `f(e)=e^2-n`, and we ask how much we have to change `e` to get rid of this error.  Since the rate of change of `f` is `f'(x)`, which is `2e` at the point `(e,e^2-n)`, we should divide `e^2-n` by `2e` to work out how much we have to adjust `e` by, to get our next estimate.

That is, our next estimate should be

```
  e - (e^2-n) / 2e
= e - (e / 2)  + (n / 2e)
= (e + n / e) / 2
```

More information on Newton's algorithm can be found at 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/NewtonsMethod.aspx (which has a lovely diagram that explains how it works) and at http://www.math.brown.edu/UTRA/linapprox.html which goes into some of the more technical detail.